# How does Oracle handle db connections?

Tags: oracle, connection

How does Oracle server handles db connections? Specifically

1. Does it provide unique id for each connections to client?
2. How does it handle/close connections for which clients are not alive?

Regards,
Sachin

Comment: better to post two separate questions. Also, what have you tried? What documentation have you read? Any code samples. Please have a look at the guidelines on questions.

Comment: It may also depend on the application - especially if it is using connection pooling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.
1. Assuming that you are using a dedicated architecture each session is given a Session ID (column SID in V$SESSION)

2. Oracle does not pick up on dead connections unless you set SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME in the server's sqlnet.ora file

Daniel